# why there is difference between b5 printed books?

Tags: paper-size, layout

I setup my environment and geometry to b5paper size, but when I print it to compare with some book references I see some difference.

So when I check the exact paper size of those books they don't have exact b5 paper size which is 176x250.

instead: 175x245, 174x244

my latex code is:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, layout=b5paper, twoside, verbose, nofoot, showframe, showcrop]{geometry}
```

Comment: What code? I have the correct the B5 size. I'm asking why printed B5 books differ a little in their size ?

Comment: @Feras Without some more information we've no real idea exactly how you are setting the size or how you are doing the comparison.

Comment: I just added them

Comment: why are you specifying `a4paper`  ? 1geometry's only use of `b5paper` is `\@namedef{Gm@b5paper}#1{\Gm@setsize{#1}(176,250){mm}}% ISO B5`  which seems to be the size you expected

Comment: for print propose to be able to measure and compare

Comment: specify b5paper and then see the pdf media box using `pdfinfo` or similar utilities.  You have not said what you have actually done or what you are measuring.

Comment: when I print it and use a rule to measure the cropped area. it matches exactly the standard 176x250. My question is: why other printed books when I measure their papers by the ruler have different few mm in their size as the examples above?

Comment: That sounds more like a question for publishers... please don't misunderstand me, the question is interesting by itself, but it simply has nothing to do with TeX. Anyway, a quick look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_size shows that "octavo" is a fairly broad denomination. Furthermore, after folding the pages are trimmed, so depending on the used machines a few mm difference sounds quite normal.

Comment: Many thanks. Your answer is more than enough

Comment: Most books are printed on paper, then bound, and then the resulting piles of paper are trimmed to give a uniform shape. Paperbacks can be printed on the final page size as the sheets are piled up uniformly and then glued along the spine., usually producing a rectangular block of paper. It is different for hardback books if they are assembled using the traditional sewing of folded sheets of pages when the result is a very ripply foredge which then need trimming to get the desired rectangular block. Essentially the size of a book has little to do with the size of the paper it is printed on.